# update asset url on free slider revolution version 6.5.25

Tags: plugins, publish

I am trying to change the local environment of my wordpress (**fireide.local**) to a public environment. I have used **velvet-blues-update-urls** to change the url, I have selected all the options in **velvet-blues-update-urls**:
[image]

when I navigate to my new domain, I can see my site and its assets, but the assets they have used in the '**slider revolution**' are still pointing to the local environment. This is your route:
[image]

To add the images in the '**slider revolution**' I have used images from '**media library**' and I have uploaded them to wordpress, even through the administration panel I can go to the gallery and there are all the images and with the updated path. I'm using a free version of **slider revolution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

surely @caleb's answer is the best but right now I can't use it. I used the response found in: [Need to Replace Old URL with New URL in Revolution Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924898/9301998).

here I put the steps:

1. I export the slider in the local environment.

[image]

2. then in the slider-revolution section we go to '**Manual Import**'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slider Revolution has an add-on for changing the domain:

> Use the Domain Switch AddOn to change Image URLs in sliders from one domain to another.

Source: https://www.sliderrevolution.com/documentation/domain-switch-addon/.

Comment: do I need the pro slider revolution version to install add-ons?

Comment: The article does not mention its only available with Pro. Should be simple enough to follow the directions and see if the add-on is listed.